# Virtual method call in constructor refactoring

Tags: c#, oop, refactoring, virtual-functions

I have a `Client` class which accepts an object with `IConfiguration` interface in the constructor.

Configuration should be validated when `Client` object is created.

```
public interface IConfiguration
{
    int ReconnectDelay { get; }
}

public class Client
{
    public Client(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        if (configuration.ReconnectDelay < 60000)
        {
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException();
        }
    }
}
```

For testing purposes I need a client with `ReconnectDelay` property set to a value which is less than valid.

Here's my current solution:

```
public class Client
{
    public Client(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        ValidateConfiguration(configuration);
    }

    protected virtual void ValidateConfiguration(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        if (configuration.ReconnectDelay < 60000)
        {
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException();
        }
    }
}

public class TestClient : Client
{
    public TestClient(IConfiguration configuration)
        : base(configuration)
    {
    }

    protected override void ValidateConfiguration(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
    }
}
```

It works, but causes call to virtual method in constructor, which is bad (I know that right now it will do no harm, but I want to fix this anyway).

So, is there any elegant solution for this?

Comment: Can you make the class `TestClient` to be `sealed`?

Comment: @Dmitry How that's going to help? Honest question.

Comment: @Dmitry, I can make the `TestClient` sealed, but the issue here is with the `Client` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a Validator interface with 2 implementations and then delegate to the validator.  Technically, this is still a virtual call but its to another object so you don't have to worry about subclasses of `Client` overriding the call or accessing the partially built Client.

```
public interface IValidator
{
    bool Validate (IConfiguration configuration);
}
```

Then your normal usecase uses a ReconnectionValidator.

```
public class ReconnectionValidator : IValidator
{

     bool Validate (IConfiguration configuration)
     {
       return configuration.ReconnectDelay >= 60000;
     }
}
```

Your test Validator can always return true

```
public class NullValidator : IValidator
{

     bool Validate (IConfiguration configuration)
     {
       return true;
     }
}
```

Your Client code would then take both the `IValidator` and an `IConfiguration` in its constructor and test if the validator validates the configuration.

```
public Client(IConfiguration configuration, IValidator validator)
{
   if(!validator.Validate(configuration))
   {
        throw new ConfigurationErrorsException();
    }
}
```

The bonus of this technique is you can change the validator later or have a new implementation that chains several validators together to support "or"ing and "anding" validators together.

Comment: Thanks, I like your solution.

Comment: @bniwredyc great.  I just fixed a typo in my ReconnectionValidator code which would have failed since I had the boolean logic backwards